# HTML5 vs Native App : Which to choose ??

Tags: android, iphone, html, windows-phone-7, mobile

This question is quite popular, and there are already lot of questions pertaining to it. But some of them are old (like 6 months back), and for the current date - May 2012 ... it will be awesome if you can type out which one is better as of now !

I am working on some apps right now, and cross-platform functionality is a major deal here. I would like to know if I can use HTML5 for the following features.

1. **Creating a music player** in my app (will need to read all playlists and play them) - HTML5 (or) Native ?
2. **Accelerometer usage** - HTML5 (or) Native ?
3. **Camera usage** - HTML5 (or) Native ?
4. Using **gestures** (swype, etc..) - HTML5 (or) Native ?
5. **Multi-touch capabilities** & gestures - HTML5 (or) Native ?
6. **Developing 3D game** (or) 2.5D with physics - HTML5 (or) Native ?   (Native might be the best deal here, but I am curios to know how HTML5 would do in multi-platform game dev)

If you can number the options with the correct answer, and give a reason as to why I would have to use native / html5, that would be awesome :)

---

Also, what are your thoughts on `Phone-Gap` for native support ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Creating a music player in my app** - Both. HTML5 might be tedious.

**Accelerometer usage** - Native. Html5 won't support it

**Camera usage** - Native. Html5 won't support it

**Using gestures** - Native. Html5 can support it, but you'll have to use an external library

**Multi-touch capabilities & gestures** - I'd say native, for the ease of development

**Developing 3D game (or) 2.5D with physics** - Both, some great libraries are now available for both systems. However doing what you want in HTML5 is probably not easy at the moment.

More generally, HTML5 gives you the possibility to write you code once for every system and then wonder if it'll work in the same way everywhere. Native apps require a specific development for each platform, with the costs and the problems of maintaining many softwares at different stages of maturity that it leads.

However if you don't need specific features, go for HTML5. It's still a bit tedious to write code on it so far, but the quality and the amount of available libraries is increasing every day. Use [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), it'll save you headaches.

If your application is designed with [responsive design](http://designmodo.com/responsive-design-examples/) in mind, you'll also be able to support computers, tablets and smartphones in one application.

Comment: I would choose native for all this features

Comment: Good Answer - might I also add that HTML5 Audio and HTML5 Video is not supported in all devices - some devices and browsers do not support mp3 for example or other formats. Otherwise after nearly 2 years of mobile development this question fits the build.... Look at Titanium they are going Windows Mobile soon - my best advice though if your company has budget and time and developers and the project is a like a game complex - Use cocoa for Apple, Java for Android and c# for WP7 - separate platform releases like Angry Birds for example.

Comment: Great answer ! Phone gap seems to leverage on those issues - http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/index.html . What do you think about that ?

Comment: Is it true that Camera usage needs to be native? I think if you use PhoneGap it works.

Comment: We had performance issues with PhoneGap so as all answerers here say, it depends how complex your app is.

Answer (score 16):

Unless your app is extremely simple then avoid the so-called cross-platform solutions and build native for each platform. If you do, you will be glad.

If you don't then you will be very sorry when something breaks on some devices but not others, or when you get a request to add certain capabilities that some devices won't support.

Basically using a cross-platform solution is lowest common denominator / only suitable for simple apps / false economy in my experience.

Just my humble opinion based upon 12+ years of commercial software development and experience of trying both approaches myself.

Comment: Phone gap seems to leverage on those issues - http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/index.html . What do you think about that ?

Comment: I think I would expect phoneGap docs to have a different opinion to me, they're trying to "sell" phoneGap. I also think it would be sensible to realise that cross-platform "solutions" will not support the latest and greatest features as soon as they are released either.

Comment: I see what you mean. I was just interested to know how phoneGap was able to achieve native capability. But yes, what you say makes sense :) Thanks  !

Comment: cross-platform is not equal to none-native! many 3d games are cross-platform and native. In some frameworks and languages you can build your apps as native and you will have greet features and hardware control. for an example of this kind of cross-platform frameworks is <the Qt>. It uses its own C++ libraries and presents greet performance and control over hardware. I developed some android apps using Qt and yes it makes some hardness and many pros. So I think you chose a bad option for cross-platform app development. Look at other cross-platform options :)