# HTML5 vs native

Tags: html, native

i've read article on here but it is dated back may 2012
[HTML5 vs Native App : Which to choose ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648459/html5-vs-native-app-which-to-choose)

so i wanna know is there any changes at this moment..

Answer (score 2):

It **depends**. You can't have a winner here. Both have cons and pros, so you have to decide upon those factors, what suits you best and of course what language you are most familiar coding with.

**NATIVE APPLICATIONS PROS**

- Better performance and user experience
- Not bound to the browser
- Full mobile functionality access (camera, microphone, contacts, etc.)

**HTML5 (web app) PROS**

- Multiple platform support (single application)
- Easy Maintenance
- Scalable

But I don't understand why [HTML5 vs Native App : Which to choose ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648459/html5-vs-native-app-which-to-choose) didn't cover you. As long as I can tell, nothing has changed and the selected answer is very informative.

Comment: Hi M.spyratos, Thanks for the info..
as i google on the web and realize that a lot of people have been saying HTML5 is rising slowly so i'm afraid that the HTML5 vs Native App : Which to choose ?? might be slightly outdated :)

thanks..

Comment: No problem! It's not outdated... The main problem with native applications is the high cost of maintenance across all platforms. Web apps are displayed through the browser, so as long as your web app is cross-browser compatible, you don't need to worry about all the different platforms. One thing though. A web app must be light to be fast on a mobile device, which sometimes means sacrificing design for performance.

Comment: Good answer (although "cons" should read "pros" for both of your lists). Also, there is the "Hybrid" solution which is an HTML5 app wrapped inside of a Native mobile App which in some situations might let you "have your cake and eat it too"